# Neo4J - Ordering results (list of maps) by node property

Tags: neo4j, properties

How do I order my results by node property?

```
RETURN DISTINCT p, COLLECT(DISTINCT {personID: person.id, personName: person.name, personOrder: person.orderNumber}) AS personInfo
```

I've tried `ORDER BY personOrder` but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: **You need to sort the data before collecting.** Can you share the complete query?

Answer (score 2):

We can't sort the collection directly. Collection can be sorted with UNWIND and ORDER BY. Then collect again. **Another way is to sort on the these before collecting.**

**Replace `RETURN` by `WITH`. Sort and Collect again:**

```
WITH p, COLLECT(DISTINCT {personID: person.id, personName: person.name, personOrder: person.orderNumber}) AS personInfo
UNWIND personInfo AS person
WITH p, person ORDER BY person.personOrder
RETURN p, collect(person) AS personInfo;
```

Comment: No need for DISTINCT in your first line, when you aggregate (such as by using `collect()` the grouping key (the non-aggregation terms) become distinct naturally.